# I want to know about common resident permit

Tags: uk, europe, danish-residents

Please is there anyone here who can explain better what the UK government website means by (a Common Resident Permit issued by EEA countries.)

Comment: Perhaps you can add a link to that website ?

Comment: This is mostly called **uniform format for residence permits**. See Annex of:  [EUR-Lex - 32017R1954 - EN - EUR-Lex](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=uriserv:OJ.L_.2017.286.01.0009.01.ENG&toc=OJ:L:2017:286:FULL) for a sample image. They are a common format as a plastic card (as apposed to a stamp or sticker in the passport).

Comment: Please do not type in all capital letters.